# Should I choose linear time or quadratic time in the following code?

Tags: asymptote

Example:

1.

```
unitsize(1cm);
size(300);
path polygon(... pair[] K){
path p;
for(int i=0;i<K.length;++i){
  p=p--K[i];
}
return p--cycle;
}

draw(polygon((0,0),(3,0),(3,3),(1.5,5),(0,3)),dashed);
shipout(bbox(2mm,invisible));
```

2.

```
unitsize(1cm);
size(300);
path polygon(... pair[] K){
guide p;
for(int i=0;i<K.length;++i){
p=p--K[i];
}
path g=p--cycle;
return g;
}

draw(polygon((0,0),(3,0),(3,3),(1.5,5),(0,3)),dashed);
shipout(bbox(2mm,invisible));
```

Both have the same output but I should choose which (such as about `processing times`)?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking.  It seems like the only difference is (1) has `return p--cycle;`, while (2) assigns to `g` and then has `return g;`.  Is that the only difference?  I don't see how that would have any affect on anything, and would recommend that you pick what you want.

Comment: In the first example, `p` is declared as a `path`; in the second example, it is declared as a `guide`. The second approach should be *much* faster if you have a very large number of points (linear time is better than quadratic). But for the size of polygon given here, I doubt it makes much difference, and it is even possible the first could be faster.

Comment: @CharlesStaats Your comment is useful for me. Thanks.